# Getting error when replace HttpService from @nestjs/common to @nestjs/axios

Tags: axios, nestjs, nestjs-config

Getting error when switched HttpService from nestjs@common to nestjs/axios.

```
@Injectable()
export class AxiosClient implements OnModuleInit {
  private interceptors: AxiosInterceptor[];
  constructor(
    private httpService: HttpService,
    private authInterceptor: AuthInterceptor,
    private httpsInterceptor: AgentInterceptor,
    private classTransformationInterceptor: ClassTransformationInterceptor
  ) {
    this.interceptors = [
      this.classTransformationInterceptor,
      this.authInterceptor,
      this.httpsInterceptor,
      this.userInterceptor,
    ];
  }


  onModuleInit(): void {
    const interceptorManager = this.httpService.axiosRef.interceptors;
    this.interceptors.forEach((interceptor) => {
      interceptorManager.request.use((request) =>
        interceptor**.onRequest(request)**
      );
```

On Response and request.
Argument of type 'AxiosRequestConfig' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AxiosRequestConfig'.

```
      interceptorManager.response.use(
        (response) => interceptor.onResponse(response),
        // Using the Promise.reject is to keep the error passed from each interceptor and thrown out to the consumer
        (error) => Promise.reject(interceptor.onResponseRejected(error))
      );
    });
```

Types of property 'method' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Method'.

Getting error in line onRequest and onResponse when passing the request response.

Its throwing the error when i am fetching the HttpService from nestjs/axios instead of nestjs/common

Comment: Can you highlight where you're seeing that error? I don't see a `method` in your code above. It's probably just a types package version issue

Comment: I am getting this error, onResponse or onRequest

Comment: the error got resolved with nestjs/common@8.0.0 instead of nestjs/axios

Comment: I get that, you mentioned that in your issue, but there's something in the `axios` types version that's causing the issue

Comment: @Krish909 post it _as answer_, and [accept](/help/accepted-answer) it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error got resolved with nestjs/common@8.0.0 instead of nestjs/axios